# used is_displayed() function on python selenium though it giving no such element found error

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I was trying to use if else condition if(element displayed): do something else continue.
Here is my code:

```
if driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//span[contains(text(),'Create a public post…')]").is_displayed():
send keys and input file....
else:
print("nothing")
```

but i am getting this error:

> selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such
> element: Unable to locate element:
> {"method":"xpath","selector":"//span[contains(text() ,'Create a public
> post…')]"}   (Session info: chrome=91.0.4472.124)

My intention was if I couldn't find the element it will continue to run instead of abruptly closing the browser. I don't want to use TRY except.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably you have to add some wait / delay to let the element fully loaded before validating if it is displayed.
So your code can be something like this:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)

try:
    wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//span[contains(text(),'Create a public post…')]")))
    #send keys and input file....
except:
    print("nothing")
```

Also possibly your locator is wrong or maybe the element is inside an iframe etc.

Answer (score 0):

This action does not exist as a predefined function, and the easiest way to check for an element is to simply call **find_element** inside **try/except**.

- You can also create a function in which you use try/except and then you can use that function in your code.